# How to highlight entered text?

Tags: typescript, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap -> typeahead.

If we use array of objects, entered value is not highlighting in dropdown.

Please refer `Template for results` example in this link
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

I need to highlight entered text. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In `typeahead-template.html`, rather than using the following template:

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/' + r['flag']" width="16">
  {{ r.name}}
</ng-template>
```

You can use this template:

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/' + r['flag']" width="16">
  <ngb-highlight [result]="r.name" [term]="model"></ngb-highlight>
</ng-template>
```

This uses the `ngb-highlight` directive exposed by ng-bootstrap in order to highlight occurrences of the search term in the typeahead result.

Please see [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VCTY0rKBeq33IweBuboR?p=preview) for a working demo.